# Symfony 3.0 and HWIOAuthBundle not working together?

Tags: php, hwioauthbundle, symfony

I want to install HWIOAuthBundle in a Symfony 3.0 project. It seems that there is a capping on dependencies and HWIOAuthBundle 0.4 is working only with prior versions of Symfony 3.0.

Is there any 0.5 version of HWIOAuthBundle rolling or do I have to replace symfony 3.0 with an older version to make it work?

I'm receiving this error message:

```
$ composer require hwi/oauth-bundle

 Using version ^0.4.0 for hwi/oauth-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for hwi/oauth-bundle ^0.4.0 -> satisfiable by hwi/oauth-bundle[0.4.0].
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - hwi/oauth-bundle 0.4.0 requires symfony/options-resolver ~2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/options-resolver[v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.8.0].
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.26|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.27|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.28|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.29|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.30|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.31|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.32|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.33|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.34|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.35|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.3.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.4.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.4.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.4.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.4.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.4.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.4.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.4.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.5.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.5.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.5.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.5.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.5.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.5.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.5.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.5.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.5.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.5.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.5.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.5.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.5.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.6.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.6.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.6.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.6.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.6.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.6.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.6.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.6.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.6.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.6.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.6.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.6.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.6.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.7.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.7.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.7.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.7.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.7.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.7.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.7.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v2.8.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.0.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: Quite a few 3rd party bundles have not been updated for S3.  You can check the bundle site for specific information.  But if you need something in the short term then either patch the bundle yourself or use 2.8.

Comment: For the moment I've reverted back to symfony 2.8. Maybe the capping has been enforced because of some design differences. I'll check out if patching before a new release of HWIOAuthBundle is possible  for me to do it.

Comment: This bundle seems to have an explicit dependency on `symfony/yaml` and a few other things which is strange because it's a bundle and it should therefore only have a dependency on the Symfony framework, not individual packages of that framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no official release yet. But you can follow latest dev like this:

```
"symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
"hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.5.*-dev"
```

Here is an issue https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/issues/931